# Parameters to watch while running an application on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am running an application overnight on my Linux xscale device. I am looking for things,which would increase with the increase in the amount of time of running.
One thing,is the memory. If you observe the memory on the xscale systems,the free memory would start decreasing,but you will see an increase in the cached memory. What are the other parameters which we can observe ,e.g. can we observe the amount of stack or heap usage?

Comment: probably belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is developed by you, i would recommend the following heap profiler to use for getting more deeper details.

http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/wiki/GooglePerformanceTools

Answer (score 0):

`vmstat` is often a good thing to run; it gives detailed information about memory, swap, & cpu usage,  as well as the average number of interrupts & context switches per second.  Give it a number, n, and it will run continuously every n seconds.